# How to use a stored FetchRequest with NSFetchedResultsController?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

`NSFetchedResultsController` provides a lot of nice stuff free when working with tableViews.  I also understand that storing fetch requests in the model is good form.  Can I use both of these together for super core data goodness?  If so, how so?

This example from Mr. Zarra's excellent book shows the template returning an array and I've failed in my attempts to get a fetchedResultsController back.

```
- (NSArray*)retrieveBigMeals {

NSManagedObjectContext *moc = [self managedObjectContext]; 
NSManagedObjectModel *mom = [self managedObjectModel]; 
NSFetchRequest *request = [mom fetchRequestTemplateForName:@"bigMeals"]; 

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; 

if (error) {
[NSApp presentError:error]; return nil;
} return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the ios navigation based application template with core data. They already have the code for using NSFetchedResultController there.

Comment: I want to use BOTH NSFetchedResultsController & a stored fetch request.